# Colors for my prompt set in my .bashrc do not appear when I open a new terminal, but only when I source it again. How do I fix this?

Tags: shell, unix, sh, bash

I make my prompt git aware and with colors in my `~/.bashrc`, but when I open a new non-login shell it is all white. If I echo something in my `~/.bashrc` I am able to see it. So my bashrc is actually being run but I suspect something runs after it that resets things. How do I identify which file this is. The colors appear only when I source `~/.bashrc` so my ~/.bashrc itself seems to be working fine.

Comment: Try setting `set -xv` after changing the prompt in `.bashrc` to debug.

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` and see if it's still white. If so, it's a bug in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Nope. When I source it I can see all colors.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your thoughts. The real issue was with my `~/.bashrc`. I had been checking if my terminal was a color terminal before I executed the git-aware prompt and setting colors, but I did my `export TERM=term-color` only at the end. So it was working fine when my `~/.bashrc` was sourced twice instead of once. Now that I moved the export to the top, it was working fine.